# C# How to determine if a number is a multiple of another?

Tags: c#

Without using string manipulation (checking for an occurrence of the `.` or `,` character) by casting the product of an int calculation to string.

and

without using try / catch scenarios relying on errors from data types.

How do you specifically check using C# if a number is a multiple of another?

For example 6 is a multiple of 3, but 7 is not.

Comment: Looks like homework to me. Tagged as such.

Comment: homework? Not homework, I read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Try

```
public bool IsDivisible(int x, int n)
{
   return (x % n) == 0;
}
```

The modulus operator % returns the remainder after dividing x by n which will always be 0 if x is divisible by n.

For more information, see [the % operator on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx).

Comment: % or mod in vb calculates what's left over after you do a devision, for example 25 % 6 = 1. So if it's 0, there's no left over so the first must be a multiple of the second.

Comment: Given a number n, it can be expressed in terms of another number m thusly: n = k*m + r. For example 6 = 1 * (4) + 2 or 6 = 2 * (3) + 0. 
x % y returns just the 'r' term in the aforementioned formula.

Comment: Old question but just for future reference, this only holds true when `n > x` otherwise the result is `x` instead of `0`. So the correct approach for a multiple number would be `return n >= x && x % n == 0`

Comment: @PedroC88 Yes, indeed 8 % 9 returns 8, so 8 is not a multiple of 9. That is the expected behaviour of the 'IsDivisible' function.

Comment: You don't need the brackets. "%" has a higher order of precedence than "=="

Comment: Slight necro, but 0.0M % x == 0, where x is an arbitrary decimal. Is there a better way that covers this?

Answer (score 18):

```
bool isMultiple = a % b == 0;
```

This will be true if a is a multiple of b

Answer (score 14):

Use the modulus (`%`) operator:

```
6 % 3 == 0
7 % 3 == 1
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't get that part about the string stuff, but why don't you use the modulo operator (`%`) to check if a number is dividable by another? If a number is dividable by another, the other is automatically a multiple of that number.

It goes like that:

```
   int a = 10; int b = 5;

   // is a a multiple of b 
   if ( a % b == 0 )  ....
```

Comment: Thanks, some example code I've seen on the net use string manipulation on the product to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem using the modulus operator (%), but it did not work. What worked for me was (12 is an example, it can be any number, **i** is an integer number):

```
double v1 = i / 12.0;
int v2 = i / 12;
double dif = v1 - v2;
bool boolDif = false;
if (dif==0.0)
{
   boolDif = true;
   //more code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we do in the case of having doubles to compare.
E.g. value == 1.2d and baseValue == 0.1d shall give **true** and 1.2d and 0.5d shall give **false**:

```
    public static bool IsMultipleOf(double value, double baseValue)
    {
        var d = value / baseValue;
        return Math.Abs(d - Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)) <= 1E-05;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

followings programs will execute,"one number is multiple of another" in

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main
{
int a,b;
printf("enter any two number\n");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
if (a%b==0)
printf("this is  multiple number");
else if (b%a==0);
printf("this is multiple number");
else
printf("this is not multiple number");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question for C#, it is not C/C++

Answer (score -2):

there are some syntax errors to your program heres a working code;

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a,b;
printf("enter any two number\n");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
if (a%b==0){
printf("this is  multiple number");
}
else if (b%a==0){
printf("this is multiple number");
}
else{
printf("this is not multiple number");
return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Question for C#, it is not C/C++